# How does flutter order the array returned by find.byIcon?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three add buttons, one button in the `appBar` and two buttons in the `body` of the `Scaffold`. Only the button in the `appBar` will increase the count, the rest do nothing.

I wrote a test to tap the add button in the `appBar`. `find.byIcon(Icons.add)` will return 3 buttons in an array. I had assumed the first item will be the button in the `appBar` because it is vertically higher than the buttons in the `body`. But it is not the case, instead, the `appBar` button becomes the last item in the array.

Fail

```
await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add).first);
```

Success

```
await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add).last);
```

I cannot find in the doc why this is the case. Why does the button in the `appBar` appears last and not first in the array even though it is vertically higher?

I have attached the full code.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(children: [
          Text(widget.title),
          IconButton(onPressed: _incrementCounter, icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
        ]),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'First add button, does nothing',
                ),
                IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'Second add button, also does nothing',
                ),
                IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

widget_test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:pokemon/main.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());

    // Verify that our counter starts at 0.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

    // Tap the '+' icon and trigger a frame.
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add).last); // Why is it last and not first?
    await tester.pump();

    // Verify that our counter has incremented.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok from the code that you have posted is see you are using by Icon. But you know from which Iconbutton you want to add. So why don't you make use of keys to find the widget instead of the byIcon. I have created and example for you based on your code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(children: [
          Text(widget.title),
          IconButton(key: const Key('firstAdd'), onPressed: _incrementCounter, icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
        ]),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'First add button, does nothing',
                ),
                IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'Second add button, also does nothing',
                ),
                IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Test File

```
import 'package:download_file/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());

    // Verify that our counter starts at 0.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

    // Tap the '+' icon and trigger a frame.
    await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('firstAdd'))); // Why is it last and not first?
    await tester.pump();

    // Verify that our counter has incremented.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Let me know this works for you.

Comment: Yes, I know that this works as I have used key before, I am more looking for an explanation on how the array returned by `find.byIcon` is ordered. I think my title is not clear, I have edited it.